# JavaScript Regex select a word between two words

Tags: javascript

Helllo, ajax request returs me a string, that I store in a variable:

```
text = "bla bla bla word1 unknown. Word2 bla bla bla";
```

I know the every word in the text except the 'unknown'. I need to store the 'unknown' word in a variable to do further work. I know that it can be done by Regex, but I don't quite understand it. Can someone show me the trick? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you look up Regex with doctor google? What did you try?

Comment: If it's always a fixed length string, just use `substr()` to extract the portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`word1\s+([^.]*).\s*Word2` should do it.

More generally,

```
word1\s+(\S+)\s+[wW]ord2
```

This will find the "word" (non-space characters) preceded by "word1" and followed by "word2" or "Word2".  The only thing possibly necessary would be to remove non-word characters (like the period).

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but how to save this in a variable?
Like this?

   data = RegExp('word1'\s+([^.]*).\s*'word2', data);

Comment: `new Regexp(word1 + "regex" + word2)`. Remember to escape anything that uses a backslash with another backslash. Example: `var regex = /\w/` is the same as `var regex = new RegExp("\\w")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple **.match** like this.

```js
text = "bla bla bla word1 word i want Word2 bla bla bla";
myWord = text.match("word1(.*)Word2")[1];
console.log(myWord);
```